# How do you create webpages on a local IP address so that others who are connected to a same Wi-Fi network can access it?

Tags: macos, wifi, sharing, lan, file-sharing

I'm using a Mac. I have observed that some iPhone apps can create a local address (like 192.168.10.1) and if my computer is connected to the same Wi-Fi network with my iPhone, I can go to that address and see something (or download something).

I want to know that how can I use this technic to share files from my Mac to other PCs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for SO. Try apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to set up is called an Ad Hoc network. 
Here is a tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyXp4IzhvTg